# Cross platform git hooks

Tags: git, shell, cross-platform, githooks

How do you manage git pre/post commit hooks across various platforms (say, *nix and windows)?

Any best practices recommended for this scenario?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The git hooks are really no different than any shell script in that the best-practices for keeping them "cross-platform" apply just the same.  The minor difference is that you may also be targeting the Windows *nix emulation layers as major users of these hooks as well, and these can be comparatively crippled by comparison to most actual Unix environments.

I just ported a post-commit hook (and wrote a pre-commit hook) to the default Git for Windows, which uses MINGW32.  A few of the changes I had to make since the previous version made some assumptions about the scripting environment available:

- no `readlink` available, but it was ineffectual on Windows anyway, so I just hacked in a check of `which readlink` and no-oped if there was none
- redirecting to `/dev/null` doesn't work in Windows, instead you have to redirect to `nul`, to do this I just did a `uname -s` check and set a variable for what to redirect to
- no `mktemp` available, but since it was a directory that we ended up pruning anyway, we used a naively hard-coded directory name
- for some reason, redirecting of STDOUT via `exec >>$out` works fine in MINGW32, but `exec 2>>$err` for STDERR does not (it seems to die silently), so unfortunately we just had to eschew that redirection

Other than that, it worked pretty well as-is because there wasn't a lot of platform-specific "stuff" in it.  So just stick to best practices for making cross-platform scripts and that should get you at least 80% of the way there.  After that, test test test in all of the various environments you're targeting.

Comment: Of course, there's no requirement that a git hook be a shell script - in fact, there's at least one in git's contrib directory in Perl.

Comment: @Jefromi good point, though the [shell] tag leads me to believe that he is doing it in shell script, but maybe he doesn't know he has to so +1